# How can I create a nested value in TinyDB using python3?

Tags: python-3.x, tinydb

An example is this:

```
from tinydb import TinyDB, Query
from tinydb.operations import add

db = TinyDB('tinydb_practice.json')

db.insert({'Name':'Bella', 'Places':{}})
db.update(add('Places', {{'Country':'USA'}}))

for item in db:
  print(item)
```

What I want as my result is

```
{'Name':'Bella', 'Places':{{'Country':'USA'}}}
```

But I get this error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

TIA! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Places` should be a list not a dict (or a set):

```
from tinydb import TinyDB, Query
from tinydb.operations import add

db = TinyDB('tinydb_practice.json')

db.insert({'Name':'Bella', 'Places':[]})  # <- replace {} by []
db.update(add('Places', [{'Country':'USA'}]))  # <- replace outer {} by []

for item in db:
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
{'Name': 'Bella', 'Places': [{'Country': 'USA'}]}
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you! Could have sworn I tried doing it this way but got an error. Anyway, this worked perfectly! :D

Comment: I apologize, I'm new to stack overflow and didn't know I needed to do so :)